# QT and OpenCV problem viewing Opencv Mat on QGraphicsView in different thread :: QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, user-interface, computer-vision

I'm developing a QT GUI for an OpenCV project, and I'm trying to display processing frame of type Mat on a QGraphicsView. I'm using a worker class to process each frame captured by the camera, then I deploy the class in a thread separated from the main window process. The system work sheltered, but in the console it gives me this error while processing the camera's frames: **QObject::killTimer: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread**.

Below the code about the worker and the main window with the thread managment:

**ProcessingFrameWorker.hpp**

```
public: 

    ProcessingImageWorker();
    ProcessingImageWorker(QGraphicsView * _showCameraFrame, 
        string _cameraRtsp);


    void process(); 

    Mat fameToShow;
    QGraphicsView * showCameraFrame;
    QGraphicsScene * scene; 
    QImage * imageToShow;
```

**ProcessingFrameWorker.cpp**

```
ProcessingImageWorker::ProcessingImageWorker(QGraphicsView * _showCameraFrame, 
    string _cameraRtsp)
    {
        showCameraFrame = _showCameraFrame;
    cameraRtsp = _cameraRtsp;
    isOpen = false;

    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this); 
    showCameraFrame->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));

    showCameraFrame->moveToThread(this->thread()); 
}

void ProcessingImageWorker::process() {

mainCap = VideoCapture(cameraRtsp); 

if (mainCap.isOpened())
{
    isOpen = true; 

    while (isOpen)
    {
        mainCap >> frameToShow; 

        cv::resize(frameToShow, frameToShow, cv::Size(showCameraFrame->width(), showCameraFrame->height()));
        imageToShow = new QImage(frameToShow.data, frameToShow.cols, frameToShow.rows, frameToShow.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        scene->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(imageToShow)); 

        showCameraFrame->fitInView(scene->sceneRect());

        showCameraFrame->show(); 

    }   

}

}
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
QThread * processingFrameThread = new QThread(); 
ProcessingFrameWorker *processingFrameWorker = new ProcessingFrameWorker(ui->graphicsView, cameraRtsp);
processingFrameWorker->moveToThread(processingFrameThread);
processingFrameThread->start(); 
connect(processingFrameThread, SIGNAL(started()), processingFrameWorker, SLOT(process()));
```

I've noticed that after a few iterations the console message disapear.

Thank's.

Comment: You can't read/write Qt GUI elements from any thread other than that on which `main` is running.  It's not supported.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this issue passing through a signal a QImage from the processing thread to the main window class.